# Oracle Update com Join - ORA-01779

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Bom dia,

Estou tentando fazer um update em uma coluna usando informações de outra tabela usando o ORACLE. Porém, estou recebendo o erro "ORA-01779: não é possível modificar uma coluna que mapeie uma tabela não preservada pela chave".

Segue script utilizado:

```
update (
    select AP.NR_ATENDIMENTO,
    PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO,
    PP.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR,
    PP.CD_FUNCAO,
    PPR.CD_MEDICO_EXEC,
    PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA,
    PP.NR_INTERNO_CONTA,
    lp.CD_MEDICO_RESP
    from atendimento_paciente ap 
    inner join PRESCR_MEDICA pm on
        AP.NR_ATENDIMENTO = PM.NR_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN PRESCR_PROCEDIMENTO PPR ON
        PM.NR_PRESCRICAO = PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO
    INNER JOIN PROCEDIMENTO_PACIENTE PP ON
        PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO = PP.NR_PRESCRICAO
        AND PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA = PP.NR_SEQUENCIA_PRESCRICAO
    LEFT JOIN LAUDO_PACIENTE LP ON
        PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO = LP.NR_PRESCRICAO
        AND PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA = LP.NR_SEQ_PRESCRICAO
    WHERE 0 = 0
    and PPR.CD_MEDICO_EXEC is not null
    and PP.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR IS NULL
    AND PPR.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO <> 78
    AND PP.NR_INTERNO_CONTA IS NOT NULL
    AND AP.DT_ENTRADA >= '01/04/2018'
    AND PP.CD_FUNCAO <> 900
    and AP.NR_ATENDIMENTO = 297106
    AND LP.CD_MEDICO_RESP IS NOT NULL
```

) Updt
set Updt.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR = Updt.CD_MEDICO_RESP;
commit;

Alguém tem uma dica de como fazer este update?

atte;

Comment: Use o Merge: http://www.oratable.com/oracle-merge-command-for-upsert/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de solucionar é utilizando [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) do oracle para fazer isto.

Ficaria algo como:

```
MERGE INTO PROCEDIMENTO_PACIENTE PP
USING (select PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO, PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA, LP.CD_MEDICO_RESP
    from atendimento_paciente ap 
    inner join PRESCR_MEDICA pm on
        AP.NR_ATENDIMENTO = PM.NR_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN PRESCR_PROCEDIMENTO PPR ON
        PM.NR_PRESCRICAO = PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO
    LEFT JOIN LAUDO_PACIENTE LP ON
        PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO = LP.NR_PRESCRICAO
        AND PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA = LP.NR_SEQ_PRESCRICAO
    WHERE PPR.CD_MEDICO_EXEC is not null
        AND PPR.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO <> 78
        AND AP.DT_ENTRADA >= '01/04/2018'
        and AP.NR_ATENDIMENTO = 297106
        AND LP.CD_MEDICO_RESP IS NOT NULL
) Updt
ON (PP.NR_PRESCRICAO = Updt.NR_PRESCRICAO
    AND PP.NR_SEQUENCIA_PRESCRICAO = Updt.NR_SEQUENCIA
    AND PP.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR IS NULL
    AND PP.NR_INTERNO_CONTA IS NOT NULL
    AND PP.CD_FUNCAO <> 900
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET PP.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR = Updt.CD_MEDICO_RESP;
```

Veja se atende.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, o Merge atendeu sim.

Só tive que fazer uma pequena mudança, pois estava apresentando a seguinte mensagem:

ORA-38104: Colunas referenciadas na Cláusula ON não podem ser atualizadas: "PP"."CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR"

Caso alguém encontre o mesmo problema que eu, segue código:

```
MERGE INTO PROCEDIMENTO_PACIENTE PP
USING (
    select PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO, PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA, NVL(LP.CD_MEDICO_RESP, PPR.CD_MEDICO_EXEC) CD_MEDICO_RESP
    from atendimento_paciente ap 
    inner join PRESCR_MEDICA pm on
        AP.NR_ATENDIMENTO = PM.NR_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN PRESCR_PROCEDIMENTO PPR ON
        PM.NR_PRESCRICAO = PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO
    INNER JOIN PROCEDIMENTO_PACIENTE PP1 ON
        PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO = PP1.NR_PRESCRICAO
        AND PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA = PP1.NR_SEQUENCIA_PRESCRICAO
    LEFT JOIN LAUDO_PACIENTE LP ON
        PPR.NR_PRESCRICAO = LP.NR_PRESCRICAO
        AND PPR.NR_SEQUENCIA = LP.NR_SEQ_PRESCRICAO
    WHERE PPR.CD_MEDICO_EXEC is not null
        AND PPR.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO <> 78
        AND AP.DT_ENTRADA >= '01/04/2018'
        AND PP1.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR IS NULL
        AND PP1.NR_INTERNO_CONTA IS NOT NULL
        AND PP1.CD_FUNCAO <> 900
) Updt
ON (PP.NR_PRESCRICAO = Updt.NR_PRESCRICAO
    AND PP.NR_SEQUENCIA_PRESCRICAO = Updt.NR_SEQUENCIA  
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET PP.CD_MEDICO_EXECUTOR = Updt.CD_MEDICO_RESP;
```

Muito obrigado pela ajuda.